# Given a transparent color, what is the same non-transparent equivalent color?

Tags: r, colors

Suppose you have a transparent color in R: "#00BFFF4C".
How to find the non-transparant color such that it looks the same on a white background?

Comment: It will just be 4C/FF times 00, BF and FF, presumably.  i.e. #00394C00, approximately.

Comment: remove the last two values from the alpha channel ...i,e, `#00BFFF` ; check `scales::alpha("#00BFFF", 0.3)`

Comment: I am sorry user20650, but that is not correct. What you propose gives a darker color than the transparent color.

Comment: @AndrewGustar It seems reasonable that it would be like that, but the color you propose doesn't like the transparent color in the question.

Comment: @Ruben Ah! Actually, FFFFFF is white, so you need to work backwards, and apply the 4C/FF factor to (FF-00), (FF-BF), etc, and then subtract that from FF again. Can't do that in my head in this cafe, but hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I now also understand how making lighter and darker works with rgb color coding.